# XML and & symbol

Tags: php, xml

I have a question about "&" symbol:

I have an return url in this format:

```
http://localhost/index.php?task=payment_return&id=113&token=750ac376e9ee1f6e87eba80c409005c4
```

I set it to XML in my PHP function, inside "url-retorno":

```
private function XMLUrlRetorno() {
    // $msg = '<url-retorno>' . $this->getData('url_retorno') . '</url-retorno>';
    $msg = '<url-retorno>' . str_replace('&', '&amp;', $this->getData('url_retorno')) . '</url-retorno>';
    return $msg;
}
```

Ok, but the problem is the "&", if my url are written in this format:

```
http://localhost/index.php?task=payment_return&id=113&token=750ac376e9ee1f6e87eba80c409005c4
```

Or

```
http://localhost/index.php?task=payment_return&amp;id=113&amp;token=750ac376e9ee1f6e87eba80c409005c4
```

I get this error from XML:

```
error: Unexpected end of file after url-retorno
```

I have tried with htmlspecialchar, with str_replace('&', ..) and again error..

What to do, if 'url-retorno' have not "&" it's working propertly,  but if have, not?

The XML send:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<requisicao-transacao id="c1303587fb566fdec7ae480f5b8d3e04" versao="1.1.0">
  <dados-ec>
    <numero>0000000000</numero>
    <chave>a00000000a0000000000a0000000aa0000a0000000000a0aaa0a0000aa0aa000</chave>
  </dados-ec>
  <dados-pedido>
    <numero>185</numero>
    <valor>15</valor>
    <moeda>986</moeda>
    <data-hora>2011-11-20T13:57:51</data-hora>
    <descricao>185 - teste: 1 x $15.00</descricao>
    <idioma>PT</idioma>
  </dados-pedido>
  <forma-pagamento>
    <bandeira>visa</bandeira>
    <produto>1</produto>
    <parcelas>1</parcelas>
  </forma-pagamento>
  <url-retorno>http://localhost/index.php?task=payment_return&amp;id=185&amp;token=4babfe87206d14cc88220810d44bbb28</url-retorno>
  <autorizar>3</autorizar>
  <capturar>1</capturar>
</requisicao-transacao>
```

The XML response:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<erro xmlns="http://ecommerce.cbmp.com.br">
  <codigo>001</codigo>
  <mensagem>XML inválido: 'error: Unexpected end of file after url-retorno'.</mensagem
</erro>
```

Comment: Does it work with `$msg = '<url-retorno>' . '</url-retorno>';`? What is `$this->getData('url_retorno')`?

Comment: `$this->getData('url_retorno')` get a string with url, wich is the not escaped string `http://localhost/index.php?task=payment_return&id=113&token=750ac376e9ee1f6e87eba80c409005c4`

Comment: Work with `$msg = '<url-retorno>test</url-retorno>';` because my `url-retorno` can`t  be null/empty

Comment: What does *"get a string with url"* in your previous comment mean? Can you be more specific here please?

Comment: return an variable of type string. `return 'http://localhost/index.php?task=payment_return&id=113&token=750ac376e9ee1f6e87e‌​';`

Comment: Are you sending this XML to a web service?  The example you've pasted above is fine, if you're sure this is what's being sent then I'd say the problem is with the web service.  "Unexpected end of file" usually means there's an unclosed tag somewhere, this can happen if text content isn't encoded properly.

Comment: Yes, to cielo Credit Card payment system. I forgot a lot of time debugging it, and it is my conclusion too, the problem are not with my code, but with webservice system..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the cdata tag in your xml

```
 <![CDATA[
       Your url with & in it
     ]]>
```

This should look like this in your code and is totally xml conform.

```
    private function XMLUrlRetorno() {
        $msg = '<url-retorno><![CDATA[' . $this->getData('url_retorno') . ']]></url-retorno>';
        return $msg;

}
```

Comment: I have tried with Domdocument, but now, i get the error `unterminated entity reference `, and the string is `<url-retorno>&lt;![CDATA[http://localhost/cielo/index.php?option=com_events_booking</url-retorno>`, note the cdata not ended, because the '&' break the construction of url.. strange.

Comment: Please provide more of your code there has to be something, that breaks the cdata tag.

Comment: I have made a log of the data send, and for my surprise, the gateway of Cielo, are not working propertly with my XML correctly send. See the log posted on question.

Comment: Are you sure, you send 100% valid xml to your gateway? plaese provide us a full example of your xml output

Answer (score 2):

There are some characters that are not accepted by xml markup (read this [read this link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references).)

When you have unescaped characters, encode them using `htmlspecialchars` or the reverse method to escape them.

Comment: I have tried with htmlspecialchars, it return the same error, but with string escaped.